# Where should I ask legal questions about amateur radio?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If I have a question about amateur radio regulations, should I ask on law.se or ham.se?

Answer (score 4):

It's not uncommon for questions to be on-topic at more than one site, so I'd say both seem appropriate given the generality of the OP.

I note that Ham.SE has [these questions](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) with the [legal](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag (which has [regulations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) remapped as a synonym) and this usage guidance:

> Questions regarding laws or other legal regulations pertaining directly to amateur radio. Also tag your question with the relevant location. If in doubt, always seek professional legal advice.

From a LawSE perspective it depends on what you're asking which is not clear from the OP - if it's seeking an interpretation of what the regulations mean / allow etc then that appears okay, but if you're looking for legal advice then that's off-topic here.

LawSE has [these questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) tagged [regulations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) with this guidance:

> Regulations: these are typically used to refer to rules and administrative codes issued by governmental agencies at all levels, municipal, county, state and federal. Although they are not laws, regulations have the force of law, since they are adopted under authority granted by statutes, and often include penalties for violations.